# Error installing purescript-list

Tags: purescript

I'm new to Purescript and am following the tutorial for installation.  Purescript itself is working and I can start the CLI using `pulp psci`, but installing `purescript-list` runs into trouble.

Having entered the command `bower install purescript-lists --save`, I get a long list of package names, but when it gets to `purescript-eff` and `purescript-prelude` I run into some version conflicts:

```
bower purescript-eff#^2.0.0                            cached https://github.com/purescript/purescript-eff.git#2.0.0
bower purescript-eff#^2.0.0                          validate 2.0.0 against https://github.com/purescript/purescript-eff.git#^2.0.0

Unable to find a suitable version for purescript-eff, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) purescript-eff#^1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.0 and is required by purescript-console#1.0.0
    2) purescript-eff#^2.0.0 which resolved to 2.0.0 and is required by purescript-st#2.0.0

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer
```

A similar message is shown for `purescript-prelude`.  No matter which options I choose, both `pulp build` and `pulp run` fail with:

```
$ pulp build
* Building project in /Developer/purescript/training1
Error found:
in module PSCI.Support
at /Developer/purescript/training1/bower_components/purescript-psci-support/src/PSCI/Support.purs line 10, column 34 - line 10, column 53

  Cannot import value unsafeInterleaveEff from module Control.Monad.Eff.Unsafe
  It either does not exist or the module does not export it.


See https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Error-Code-UnknownImport for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.


Compiling PSCI.Support
* ERROR: Subcommand terminated with exit code 1
```

What have I missed here?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using psc version 0.10.* you should go with prelude, lists and eff v2*.
If you are using psc version 0.9.* you should go with prelude, lists and eff v1*.

If you are using psc 0.10.* you might want to update pulp to version 9.1.0

The problem occurs due to breaking changes between psc 0.9 and 0.10 and the relevant libraries. by writing `bower install purescript-lists --save` you are asking bower for the latest dependencies which conflict with the dependency versions specified in your `bower.json`.

Comment: Great thanks.It took a bit of fiddling around to get things working - E.G. `npm -g update pulp` only took me to 9.0.1, so I had to completely delete and reinstall it.